# Dependency injection @ Runtime

Tags: asp.net, api, model-view-controller, autofac

I have a controller that looks simplyfied as below.
I want to use Dependency injection for all my DataServices.

In the database I have several datawarehouses for each Client.
Is it possible to inject my DatawareHouseService without creating a new instance @runtime?
I first need to call the MainService to get the correct connectionstring.

```
    protected internal IMainService mainService;
    public EventController(ITeamleaderMainService MainService)
   {
        this.mainService = MainService;
   }
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]JObject Value)
   {
    var companySettings = await mainService .GetCompanySettingsByGroup(Value["Account_Id"].ToObject<int>());

    using (DataWareHouseService dwSService = new DataWareHouseService(companySettings.EntityConnectionstring()))
    {
       //Do some stuff 

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register and inject factory delegate `Func<string, DataWareHouseService>`. [Here](http://benedict-chan.github.io/blog/2014/08/13/resolving-implementations-at-runtime-in-autofac/) you can see an example.

```
using (var dwSService = _dwhClientFactory.Invoke(companySettings.EntityConnectionstring()))
{
   //Do some stuff
}
```

If you want to have single instance per client you can create `DwhClientResolver` class which could be like this:

```
public class DwhClientResolver : IDwhClientResolver 
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<DataWareHouseService>> _instances = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<DataWareHouseService>>();

    public DataWareHouseService GetClient(string connStr) => 
        _instances.GetOrAdd(connStr, x => new Lazy<DataWareHouseService>(() => new DataWareHouseService(x))).Value;
}

public interface IDwhClientResolver
{
    DataWareHouseService GetClient(string connStr);
}
```

, register it as a singleton and inject `IDwhClientResolver` in all places where you need `DataWareHouseService`.

Also you can check [keyed-services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) approach but usage of `DwhClientResolver` is simpler.

Comment: Thank U for the nice example. i will check out if this works for my problem.

Comment: The EntityConnectionString is needed in the constructor of the dwsService. I only have 1 service wich works with a diffrent connection. the example above will only solve the problem if I had a diffrent DatawarehouseService for each client.

Comment: @FrederikDeClercq Do you want to have singleton DatawarehouseService per each client?